# X2go remote access error from mac

Tags: lubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, x2go

I want to access my netbook with lubuntu from a macbook pro machine.
Here is what I did:

on lubuntu I installed `X2Go` server:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install x2golxdebindings
```

I installed X2Go client for mac version and I set up a new session:

```
Host: <my public IP>
Login: Nico
SSH port: 22
Session type: LXDE
```

When I try to connect from my mac I get this error:

```
Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
```

I’m completely new to linux so I’ve no idea what to do to make it work.

On `X2Go` client I put my login name (Nico) that appears on lubuntu whenever the screen unlocks, Is that the correct one to use? As password I used the one to unlock the lubuntu session.

Lubuntu username and computer name are `ziovelvet@netbook` if this can be useful.

Comment: your user name seems to be `ziovelvet` not `Nico`.

Comment: even changing to `ziovelvet` I get the same error:
`Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install the X2go server, just the bindings

> X2Go bindings for LXDE (package name: x2golxdebindings) will add
>   additional X2Go-related functionality to your LXDE Desktop.

You need to run `sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession` for the server.  See the [install guide](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver) for details.

On a side note, X2go depends on openssh-server which is not installed by default.  It should pull that as a dependency while installing the server, though.

Comment: when I run that on lubuntu it says:

`x2goserver is already the newest version.
x2goserver set to manually installed.
x2goserver-xsession is already the newest version.
x2goserver-xsession set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old question, but I would like to share how to connect with x2go when using public key AND password.

If you are able to login from ssh without any special setup (except for the public key, of course), then just tick the box Try auto login ... and leave the *Use RSA/DSA key for ssh connection* box empty.

[image: Sample]